# A closed subgroup of $p$-adic analytic group having same dimension is open?

Tags: gr.group-theory, profinite-groups, p-adic-groups

Let $G$ be $p$-adic analytic pro-$p$ group and $H$ a closed subgroup of $G$. Suppose that $G$ and $H$ have the same dimension as $p$-adic analytic groups.

**Question**: Is it true that $H$ is an open subgroup of $G$?

I know that it's true if $H$ is also normal in $G$, cf. [Theorem 4.8] in [Analytic Pro-P Groups].[1](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/analytic-prop-groups/FC96FCA4B4EF667EC6F035513E11DB32)

Comment: Yes. The condition forces the Lie algebra $\mathfrak{h}$ of $H$ to be the whole Lie algebra of $\mathfrak{g}$. Since the (locally defined) exponential map is open at $0$ and maps $\mathfrak{h}$ into $H$, the conclusion follows. I guess one can find these statements in Bourbaki.